# Mysql Word Association/ thesaurus DB

Tags: mysql, associations, cpu-word, thesaurus

Iv been scouring the net looking for a simple lookup thesaurus to import into mysql? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I am also looking for a word association db aswell??

Thanks

Christopher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the WordNet project:

http://wnsql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hmm. This website/link has been blocked by uBlock!

Answer (score 3):

I also found this useful: http://code.google.com/p/moby-thesaurus/

There's a MySQL dump file which you can import into MySQL directly.  It is the Moby Thesaurus and Parts-of-Speech.